# how to use vimdiff in VIM command mode?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I want to use `:vimdiff file1 file2` to diff these files in VIM command mode , but I got a error message `E492: Not an editor command: vimdiff` . do I forget something ? how to resolve it?

According Vim manual, vimdiff command should be available

Comment: perhaps you could link to your documentation. I'm pretty sure you're wrong about the documentation

Answer (score 31):

I would do:

```
:tabe file1
:vert diffsplit file2
```

if you've already widows with other buffers open in the current tab. Otherwise:

```
:e file1
:vert diffsplit file2
```

If you have two or three windows open in your current tab and they display the buffers that you want to diff, you might want to turn on diff mode for each window:

```
:windo diffthis
```

or, synonym: `windo set diff`.

*Update* - with [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) you can use `cod` to change the `diff` window setting. So use `cod` on both windows that you want to diff.

Comment: don't forget about the very useful `:diffthis`

Comment: After you are done issuing `:diffoff!` which will turn off diff mode for all windows in the current tab page.

Comment: well, thank you ! And that's to say `:vimdiff` won't be available in vim mode .

I will use `:vert diffsplit file2` instead of that.

Answer (score 9):

vimdiff is a command-line command, try it like this from inside vim

```
:!vimdiff file1 file2
```

The ! tells vim to execute a regular command.

Comment: Could also `:diffsplit`, which does the same thing but inside the already open Vim. The first file needs to be open already, however.